# map object to interface and remove all keys that don't exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to create a NestJS API with TypeORM and want to map the database user to a response model being sent to the client. My UserEntity just holds some basic information

```
@Entity('User')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  passwordHash: string;

  @Column()
  passwordSalt: string;
}
```

but obviously I can't send the password information back to the client. I created a response object just holding the relevant information

```
export interface UserRO {
  id: number;
  username: string;
}
```

When calling GET /users I would expect a collection of UserROs. So I went for

```
  public async find(): Promise<UserRO[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find(); // returning a list of UserEntities
  }
```

Unfortunately there was no mapping, so the response objects still contained the password information. I prooved it with this code

```
  public async find(): Promise<UserRO[]> {
    const dbUsers: UserEntity[] = await this.usersRepository.find();
    const roUsers: UserRO[] = dbUsers;
    console.log(dbUsers);
    console.log(roUsers); // still holding the password information

    return roUsers;
  }
```

I also added a quick fix using the map function

```
  public async find(): Promise<UserRO[]> {
    const dbUsers: UserEntity[] = await this.usersRepository.find();
    const roUsers: UserRO[] = dbUsers.map((dbUser: UserEntity) => {
      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        username: dbUser.username,
      };
    });
    console.log(dbUsers);
    console.log(roUsers); // not holding the password information anymore

    return roUsers;
  }
```

My question is: Do I really have to do this by hand? I was hoping TypeScript would remove or ignore all the "unknown" keys and only take values from the matching keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the column settings, you can add the option `select: false` to avoid including the field when selecting the entity from the database: [Hidden columns](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/hidden-columns)